# WithOptionalDependent vs WithOptionalPrinciple - Definitive Answer?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I thought it might be helpful to get a definitive answer on when to use [`WithOptionalDependent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696744%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) and when to use [`WithOptionalPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679107%28v=vs.113%29.aspx). The help for the two functions is a little unclear, and I find myself digging through multiple Stack Overflow answers and answers on other sites combining answers in order to feel confident I've got the relationship going the correct direction.

Here's what MSDN says about [`WithOptionalDependent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696744%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

> Configures the relationship to be optional:optional without a
>   navigation property on the other side of the relationship. The entity
>   type being configured will be the dependent and contain a foreign key
>   to the principal. The entity type that the relationship targets will
>   be the principal in the relationship.

and here is what it says about [`WithOptionalPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679107%28v=vs.113%29.aspx):

> Configures the relationship to be optional:optional without a
>   navigation property on the other side of the relationship. The entity
>   type being configured will be the principal in the relationship. The
>   entity type that the relationship targets will be the dependent and
>   contain a foreign key to the principal.

The line "The entity type being configured" is the part that always confuses me (and I assume others).

In this example:

```
class MyEntityA
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BId")]
    public MyEntityB B { get; set; }
}

class MyEntityB
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityA>().HasOptional(a => a.B).WithOptionalDependent();
```

is "The entity type being configured" referring to `MyEntityA` or `MyEntityB`? I assume it is the former.

If that's correct, what's an example of when you'd use `WithOptionalPrincipal`?

I actually think in my code example it should really be `WithMany` and neither of the WithOptional options. Clearly I'm still confused!

There are overloads for both of these functions that take the navigation property going the other direction. I assume those overloads don't change those answers, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

I hope this will be helpful to the larger community as well.

Answer (score 19):

For example, lets modify your `EntityB` by navigation property and make `BId` nullable (as we are talking about optional relationship).

```
class MyEntityA
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? BId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BId")]
    public virtual MyEntityB B { get; set; }
}

class MyEntityB
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual MyEntityA A { get; set; }
}
```

then we can use:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntityB>().HasOptional(a => a.A).WithOptionalPrincipal();
```

`MyEntityA` has `FK` to `MyEntityB`, so in your example you configure `MyEntityA` and use WithOptionalDependent. But you can start configuration from `MyEntityB`-side, then you need WithOptionalPrincipal.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is: "The entity type being configured" is `MyEntityA`

This can be seen definitively by looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696420(v=vs.113).aspx) for

```
OptionalNavigationPropertyConfiguration<TEntityType, TTargetEntityType>
```

which is the type returned by `HasOptional` and which says:

> TTargetEntityType
>
> The entity type that the relationship targets.

which provides more context for the phrases:

> The entity type being configured
>
> The entity type that the relationship targets

So, in your case you get back from `HasOptional` an

```
OptionalNavigationPropertyConfiguration<MyEntityA, MyEntityB>
```

Thus, `WithOptionalDependent` means that `MyEntityB` will be the Principal with an *optional* Navigation Property pointing back to `MyEntityA` (specified via the overload's lambda parameter) and `MyEntityA` will be the Dependent and contain a Foreign Key and Navigation Property (as specified in the lambda parameter of `HasOptional`).  **This is the scenario in your model.**

Conversely, `WithOptionalPrincipal` means that `MyEntityA` will be the Principal and `MyEntityB` the Dependent with Foreign Key and Navigation Property.